# Pyjnius error while making an app that connects to wifi programitically in android python

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, pyjnius

`jnius.jnius.JavaException: Cannot call instance method b'addNetwork' on class b'android/net/wifi/WifiManager'`

`3.443 24111 24278 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch 08-29 12:22:43.443 24111 24278 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch 08-29 12:22:43.443 24111 24278 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1191, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch 08-29 12:22:43.443 24111 24278 I python  :    File "/home/viraj/Desktop/Apkcreator/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Aloxen/armeabi-v7a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 55, in custom_callback 08-29 12:22:43.444 24111 24278 I python  :    File "<string>", line 8, in <module> 08-29 12:22:43.444 24111 24278 I python  :    File "/home/viraj/Desktop/Apkcreator/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 75, in Conectar 08-29 12:22:43.444 24111 24278 I python  :    File "/home/viraj/Desktop/Apkcreator/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Aloxen/armeabi-v7a/wifidroid/wifi.py", line 29, in ConnectWifiWpa 08-29 12:22:43.444 24111 24278 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 837, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.__call__ 08-29 12:22:43.445 24111 24278 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: Cannot call instance method b'addNetwork' on class b'android/net/wifi/WifiManager' 08-29 12:22:43.445 24111 24278 I python  : Python for android ended.`

Can anyone help please? i really dont know what might be causing the issue

I tried to connect to already specified wifi in android with wifidroid library in python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.